# I worked last year and went to school. Will I still get a stimulus check if nobody claimed me in 2019 taxes

Tags: united-states, irs, check, covid-19, stimulus

I worked last year for only 2 weeks. Got paid once but I still filed it on my 2019 taxes and only got back $7 but I also went to school and claimed my school payments. Nobody claimed me as a dependent last year. I am currently working but due to the virus I’m not working. So, I was wondering if I will still get a stimulus check?

Comment: Could somebody claim you? That is different than nobody claiming you.

Answer (score 1):

What matters is not whether someone actually claimed you as a dependent, but rather whether someone **can** claim you as a dependent (i.e. whether somebody meets the conditions in the law to claim you as a dependent). If someone *could have* claimed you, then you should have checked the box "Someone can claim: You as a dependent" on your 2019 Form 1040, and you would not get the stimulus check (though you can still get the payment as a tax credit on your 2020 taxes if you qualify under the 2020 tax year). If nobody could have claimed you as a dependent, then you should not have checked that box, and you would get the stimulus check.